# Building Emacs 25 on CentOS *without admin rights*

Tags: build

I'm having a hard time getting Emacs to build under CentOS 7.1 where I don't have admin rights to install dependencies.
After downloading Emacs sources I tried ./configure, and I found out that I was missing X libraries.

I grabbed the gtk3-dev libraries from an rpm repository and extracted them with:

```
rpm2cpio ../gtk3-devel-3.8.8-10.el7.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idv
```

And then I tried both:

```
GTK_LIBS=-L$HOME/tmp/gtk3/usr/lib64/ ./configure \
--prefix=$HOME/Downloads/emacs-25.1/build-out --with-x-toolkit=gtk3
```

and

```
./configure --x-includes=$HOME/tmp/gtk3/usr/include/ \ 
--x-libraries=$HOME/tmp/gtk3/usr/lib64 --with-x-toolkit=gtk3
```

but the configure script through other messages telling me that other gtk3 dependencies where missing, or that it couldn't find everything.

I was wondering if anyone knows where to find a statically build Emacs 25 for centOS x86_64, or how to build Emacs without admin rights in such a way that all dependencies are handled and installed locally?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I built mine locally in a virtual machine (e.g., Parallels running the identical version of CentOS) and then uploaded the completed/built Emacs to my website (shared server) where I did not have sufficient privileges to build.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's what I'm trying to do now. I've got the same CentOS version running on a VBox machine, but I don' t have much experience setting up all the configs (networking, users, etc) - so that is taking a lot of time.

Comment: I had never installed CentOS before the same need arose -- it was just for this particular project (i.e., to build Emacs).  I think you'll do just fine -- it is just a virtual machine, so no big deal if you make a mistake.

Comment: Could you try `fedpkg`? It worked for me on CentOS several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to create a virtual machine with Centos where I have admin rights, and compile emacs there.

When building, I added a prefix to `configure`.
That way `make install` put everything within a folder that mimicked the directory tree of the machine where I have no admin rights.

1. Install Centos on a virtual machine and grab all dependencies.
2. Get the emacs repository and run `autogen.sh`
3. Configure the build with `configure -prefix=/home/USERNAME/local/emacs`
4. Build emacs with `make install`. The installation directory is all we need.
5. Copy the install directory to the machine where you have no admin rights.
6. DONE!